# Angular JS 1.2 - binding is not working when used with a function

Tags: angularjs

I recently upgraded to `Angular JS v1.2` from v1.2rc2 and the following issue started happening.  Any help is appreciated.

I have the following code snippet:

```
<button ng-click="log('some static text plus a variable={{x}}')">Log</button>
```

where variable `x = "apple"`

when the button is clicked, it logs:

some static text plus a variable=`{{x}}`

instead of:

some static text plus a variable=apple

This issue is occurring with AngularJS 1.2 (official):

http://plnkr.co/edit/RYQO3EX5BnT67BGsuwV2?p=preview

but NOT with AngularJS 1.2-rc2 (or earlier):

http://plnkr.co/edit/aZwflh97xPlsOu1e5vle?p=preview

This is reproducible in Chrome and IE9 (and most likely in other browsers too).

Comment: It seems like the 1.2 version is right here. It should probably be `log('some static text plus a variable=' + x)`. Since you're already inside an angular expression, there's no reason to have enclosed curly braces to be evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already writing in Angular code, so ditch the `{{}}` and concatenate the variable.

```
<button ng-click="log('some static text plus a variable=' + x)"
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3SIsKdkRmDTeSqGeqUe?p=preview